# Simplify $\sin(1 + \tan{x} * \tan{\frac{x}{2}})$

Tags: trigonometry

I have to simplify $$\sin(1 + \tan{x} * \tan{\frac{x}{2}})$$ and I have got this $$\sin(\frac{1}{\cos{x}})$$
Can I even simplify more or not?

Comment: where did this questions is asked

Comment: Usually, simplifications are to be multiple-choice questions since different problems require different final simplified forms.

Answer (score 2):

That's as simple as it gets. The composition of trigonometric functions doesn't yield anything with another name. Personally, though, I'd write it as $\sin\sec x$.

Comment: $\sin(\arctan x)=x/\sqrt{1+x^2}$, which doesn't seem trigonometric to me.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe That would be a composition of a trigonometric and *inverse* trigonometric function.